# How can I boot a bootable windows 7 installer usb

Tags: ubuntu, windows, usb, bootable-media, zorin

I have a bootable usb windows 7 installer. It is working in another computer with windows 7. I want to boot it from a computer with zorin OS but I can't. I can see it from my bios menu and I can set it first in the priority list but it is not working. I think (and I may be wrong) that I have to tell zorin the usb is bootable but I don't know how. Any ideas please??
Thank you!!
I attach you a screen of the root files in my usb.[image]

Comment: While this is not a Unix question, the user seems to believe that it is. Therefore I believe that it is a valid question. If you don't think it is valid, then explain why.

Comment: This would not be a problem with the OS. If you have already set up the priority for it in the BIOS and it still isn't working, recreate the boot USB. Btw, you can tell it's pirated from the faXcooL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Unix question, though I can see why you think it is. You do not have to tell the installed OS about it.

How things work:

- Computer is switched on.
- Computer starts running program in boot ROM (often mistakenly called BIOS, on PCs).
- ROM based boot-loader, loads 2nd stage boot-loader from disk (or USB, or …).
- 2nd stage boot-loader, loads 3rd stage boot-loader from disk (or USB).
- 3rd stage boot-loader, loads operating system kernel and init process.
- init process loads the rest of the operating system.
- Operating system loads video player.
- Video player loads minecraft videos.
- User watches minecraft videos.

As you can see, the operating system does not load another operating system (except it can load a virtual-machine). The solution to you problem will be in the boot loader settings (often labelled bios settings).